# Why do definite articles precede possessive adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, articles

I am studying Italian using Duolingo. I came across the following sentence:

> Il cane ha **la mia** scarpa.

which translates to

> The dog has my shoe.

Why are possessive adjectives preceded by definite articles such as `la`, unlike Spanish?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I understand your perplexity, but how would you answer the mirror-image question: «Why in Spanish are not possessive adjectives preceded by definite articles, unlike Italian?»

Comment: Also in Catalan we use possessive adjectives preceded by definite articles: *el meu llibre*, *la meva mare*, *el teu cotxe*, *la teva cosina*, *el seu pare*...

Comment: It is just the way it is. Italian  almost always uses articles

Comment: We need to just do away with articles, like in classical Latin! That's the real solution to all this confusion. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Italian there is the *la* before *mia* because you're talking about that specific shoe. You could also have many shoes and talking about a generic shoe. In this case you can say "Il cane ha una mia scarpa".

Answer (score -1):

> > **Articles are very "strong" linguistic elements in Italian: they exercise great power over other elements, they are part of the noun, and are seldom omitted**:

*Il mio cane è bello, il tuo è brutto, rumoroso e puzza!* 
*Il tuo cane è la tua responsabilità.*
*Cane tuo - responsabilità tua! = Il cane è tuo, quindi la responsabilità è tua.*

**Very close family members do not need articles, unless I am being very specific about the family member.**

*Lei è mia sorella. Egli è suo fratello. Essa è sua nonna.* 
*Lei è la mia sorella maggiore. Egli è il suo fratello minore. Essa è la sua nonna paterna.*

**Articles may be used in front of people's names, too, especially if these people are very close to you. Such unusual linguistic behaviour is observed mainly in northern Italy.**

*La Giorgia adora il tuo cane!

[...] sono la Pia [...] (Dante)

Il Marco ha un computer nuovo.*

***Dialogo***
*A: Io sono il tuo fratello maggiore! Tu sei la mia responsabilità. 

B: È una scelta mia, non tua!

A: La scelta non è tua - non è un tuo problema! Ed una tua scelta sbagliata è anche un mio problema. Un problema tuo è anche un mio problema, perché io sono tuo fratello. Una scelta sbagliata può influenzare tutta la nostra famiglia, soprattutto la nostra sorella minore.*

> > **Possessive adjectives are still adjectives, and adjectives, in Italian, normally, wield very little influence within the articles' domain**:

- Il cane [di Marco] è molto piccolo = Il [suo] cane è molto piccolo.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!